# Sharepoint 2013 search not indexing newly added publishing pages

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search, crawling, incremental-crawl

I have a publishing page library containing all of my posts.  We are using search driven webparts to pull the search results and display to users.  What we are seeing is that after a new page is added, it is not indexed during the next incremental crawls (let's say 10-15 incremental crawls have run) or several full crawls.  Then, suddenly, the scheduled crawls will magically pick it up.  This is problematic because there are time-sensitive posts that need to show on the site relatively quickly.

Is this a bug in sharepoint?  What triggers the incremental or full crawls to pick up that a new page has been added that I am missing.  The pages are are fully published and approved and none of the settings about search result removal/library settings/etc are causing this - without changing anything else, the new page will be indexed and show in the crawl logs.

Anyone have any ideas?  We're still stuck on this one.

Comment: Are the pages published or still drafts?

Comment: Published and approved.

Comment: Nothing showing in the crawl logs?

Comment: Correct, not showing in the crawl logs until.. let's say... 4 or 6 hours later.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am seeing similar behavior on my site.

Comment: Was this resolved? I am facing the same issue

Comment: We have a similar issue with scheduled publishing pages not indexed by the crawler immediately after the "publish" has occur and the incremental crawl have run several times afterwards.